# What does the MAC address shown by `iw link` or iwconfig` represent?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have my RaspberryPi3 (latest Raspbian) connected via WiFi to my WLAN router
with `ip=192.168.1.1` and `mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A5`. However, when I perform 
the following, I get quite different results for the MAC.

```bsh
# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.198  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ...
        ether ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        ...


# arp -ni wlan0
Address            HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask     Iface
192.168.1.1        ether   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A5   C              wlan0

# iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
        ...
        addr ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:c9

# iw wlan0 link
Connected to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:a7 (on wlan0)
        ...

# iwconfig wlan0
        ...
        Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:a7

# iw --version
iw version 4.9
```

The [iw](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw) man pages, doesn't say much.

- As for `ifconfig`, it shows my own adapter MAC (`ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ:c9`).
- As for `arp`, it shows the correct WLAN router MAC (`XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:A5`).
- But for `iw wlan link`, it shows a third MAC! (`XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:a7`)!
- And for `iwconfig wlan0`, it also show that 3rd MAC.

Q. **What is that mysterious 3rd MAC address representing?**

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the info provided by @mtak we need to look at what is going on in the different [OSI layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Most IP discovery operations take place on the *Network* Layer (`L3`), whereas the [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_access_control) "stuff" happen on the *Data Link* layer (`L2`) and below (Physical).

[image]

Comment: Perhaps that's the Access Point's MAC address as per "`Access Point: ~`" and "`Connected to ~`".... [" iwconfig will display the name of the MAC protocol used "](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig) .... So the MAC address of the Wi-Fi Access Point endpoint you connect to for accessing that network via Wi-Fi.

Comment: It can't be because the AP is the one with `:A5`. I've checked this with both `nmap` and from other machines on the local network. The only other thing I can think of is that the wifi of an RPi3 can also act as a repeater. So perhaps *iwconfig* is reading the MAC of a would-be-ap or is simply buggy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `ifconfig` shows your own client's MAC address
- `arp` shows the MAC of the **IP** interface of the router, which is likely not the same as the wireless interface
- `iw wlan link` and `iwconfig wlan0` show the MAC of the wireless interface of the router

The reason that the MAC of the IP and wireless interface is not the same is that the router probably has an internal switch. The wireless interface is connected to this switch, along with the ethernet ports on the back of the router. The IP interface (the actual router) of is also connected to this switch. See this (quite crude) drawing:

[image: mac addresses]

Comment: I still don't understand what is happening here. Because, doing `nmap -sS 192.168.1.1` gives the `A5` MAC, whereas doing `airodump-ng wlan0mon` give the `A7` MAC as the BSSID. So somehow, nmap packets are just getting passed through the `A7` (wifi chip?) and instead responding to the internal router switch interface with `A5`. Is that right?

Comment: `nmap` works on layer 3 (IP). The _IP_ interface of the router is `A5`, which is what ARP/nmap will display (Layer 3). As you say the packets go right through `A7` (which is layer 1/2). Try thinking of the "router" as separate devices in a box. The first layer 3 hop your packets make will be the router, not the switching infrastructure in between (layer 1/2).

Comment: So `A5` would never be visible to anyone not already connected to the AP? Or does the WiFi router *leak* this information over the air even for non-associated clients? (I assume we are all using encrypted connections.) The question is a bit OT, but could someone spoof the `A5` MAC? I guess they could set their MAC to anything, but I fail to understand how a spoofed and non-associated MAC(A5)_a could be distinguished from the real internal MAC(A5)_b?

Comment: Yes. No. Yes. Non-associated MAC A5 would not be on the network. The real internal MAC wouldn't be in the AP authentication table, so incoming wireless packets would not be allowed from A5.